# How to force the import/loading of rest controller programatically

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm starting a spring boot rest service which may load different packages depending on the distribution. This means sometimes the distribution will contain some jars where certain REST controllers are, sometimes this controllers are not there.

So How I'm able to tell spring-boot where to find the controllers with a configuration files. Now I'm sending this info by annotations forcing me to create a "main" per distribution. I will like to define a unique main that imports the controllers defined in a file. In other words I want to access the `@Import`annotation manually as is shown in the sniped bellow:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("conf.cfg")
@Import(value = {RestContorller1.class,  RestContorller2.class})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String confFile = Const.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE;

        if(args.length>0)
            confFile= args[0];
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name",confFile);
        Boolean hasStarted = DataProcessingCore.start(confFile);
        if(hasStarted) {
            SpringApplication springApp =  new SpringApplication(Application.class);
            try {
                springApp.setDefaultProperties(Utils.createPropertyFiles(confFile));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            springApp.addInitializers();
            springApp.run(args);


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you corretly, your controllers reside in a JAR imported by `maven`/`gradle` to your main project/s.

In order to create `auto-configuration` like spring boot does, that in the same way can be used to import your controllers when the jar is in the classpath, you can tell spring to find your custom `configuration` on start-up.

I wrote a simple example for that here: [Creating your own auto-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078136/how-to-integration-test-auto-configuration-for-a-custom-spring-boot-style-starte/43086540#43086540)

In pricipal, you create a spring-boot application (without the spring boot maven plugin!! it is important for the classpath and packaging). and create a file named `spring.factories` (you can find the actual content in the guide I linked) that tells any spring-boot application that have this jar to load your configuration that may do a `@ComponentScan` to search for your controllers or set the `@Bean` manually.

Doing that, you don't have to do `@Import` and the controllers will be loaded dynamically.