# Testing with Springboot @autowire does not work with @SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I am writing Junits in springboot application , which has only one Initializer class as

```
@SpringBootApplication 

public class Initializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 @Override 
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
  application) {
      return application.sources(Initializer.class);
   }

 }
```

and other controller and service classes.

My Junit for a service class looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
@SpringBootTest  
public class ServiceTest {

           @Autowired
            private CommonUtils commonUtils;

             -----do assert cases---------

  }
```

When I am running Junit it is throwing error as:

```
    08:20:27.481 [main] ERROR 
    org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1e67b872] to prepare test instance [<ServiceTest>@5d624da6]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:308)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies (DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'. Consider annotating your test class with @ContextConfiguration.
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:276)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:304)
... 24 common frames omitted 08:20:27.532 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test class: context [[TestContext@2ef9b8bc testClass = ServiceTest, locations = [null], testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null]]], dirtiesContext [false].
```

Also I have tried with all annotations such as `@WebAppConfiguration` , @ContextConfiguration(classes = Initializer.class)`, @SpringBootConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan`, still it throws same error.
There is no other configuration classes like application context in code.

Comment: try to use it with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` instead of `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Comment: are you deploying war? it is the old and traditional deployment, some new spring features (reactive) don't even supports this deployment...

Comment: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) also did not work.

Comment: yes we are deploying war

Comment: What packages are your test class and your Boot application class in?

Comment: package name is same for both

Comment: @Patrick doesnt work

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078136/how-to-integration-test-auto-configuration-for-a-custom-spring-boot-style-starte/43212224

Answer (score 0):

You can test using annotattion @SpringBootTest, with property "classes", where you need to add your spring-boot main class:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = YOUR_MAIN_CLASS.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

Comment: I tried that too, my class now looks like :  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@SpringBootConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = Initializer.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class ServiceTest {

 ...still the error is the same

Comment: Instead of @SpringBootConfiguration, use @TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:tests.properties").  This will be the result: @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Initializer.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:tests.properties")

Comment: Please, @Harsha, could you give a feedback with the last proposed?

Comment: Didnt work with any solution, worked with @mockito annotation