# Testing starter with Springboot+JUnit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I have a custom library (a starter) created with SpringBoot. So, it doesn't have main method or `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

I want to test this starter functionality with JUnit. I have created a class in `src/test` (`TestApplication`) to be a launcher.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class SettingsTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    @Test
    public void testSettingsLoad(){
      //do smth
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

However, `TestApplication` `main` is not invoked and application context is not raised correctly.
I've tryied without `@RunWith` annotation (no Spring context at all) and with adding class directly to `@SpringBootTest` annotation (also ignored).

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43078136/how-to-integration-test-auto-configuration-for-a-custom-spring-boot-style-starte),
but it wasn't really helpful.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A starter is an auto-configuration. When i have written starters, i don't test the spring-boot application that uses the starter, i test the starter itself and this is pretty well documented in section [49.4 Testing your Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-test-autoconfig)

```
private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
    .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(UserServiceAutoConfiguration.class));

@Test
public void defaultServiceBacksOff() {
    this.contextRunner.withUserConfiguration(UserConfiguration.class)
        .run((context) -> {
            assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(UserService.class);
            assertThat(context.getBean(UserService.class))
            .isSameAs(context.getBean(UserConfiguration.class).myUserService());
    });
}
```

So what you do is that you create a ApplicationRunnerContext and then load you entryclass from your starter and then you assert in that context what has been loaded.